# Results sorted by relevance?

Tags: support, tags, search

Searching for posts by a given user with a given tag, the default sorting is by "relevance", whatever that is. Looks pretty random to me. Relevance to what? How is relevance measured, and why is it the default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SE uses elasticsearch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange).

This is what elasticsearch [has to say about relevance](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html):

- Uses TF/IDF, or [Term Frequency/Inverse Document Frequency algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)
- Computes a relevance score, based on the query
- How that score is calculated depends on the type of query clause — different query clauses are used for different purposes: a fuzzy query might determine the _score by calculating how similar the spelling of the found word is to the original search term, a terms query would incorporate the percentage of terms that were found